# Мягкий знак в глаголах

Tags: орфография

Когда на конце глаголов ставится мягкий знак?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, в неопределенной форме (всегда нужно задавать к глаголу вопрос; в неопределенной форме будет "что делать?").
Примеры: *радоваться, возвратиться*.
Во-вторых, в окончаниях второго лица единственного числа.
Примеры: *возвращаешь - возвращаешься, веселишь - веселишься*.
В-третьих, в повелительном наклонении.
Пример: *развесь - развесьте*.
В-четвертых, в частице "-сь".
Примеры: *садись, учись*.

Answer (score 0):

В неопределённой форме глагола, оканчивающейся на -ЧЬ, -ЧЬСЯ (беречь, стричь, беречься, стричься)